# Why can't I extend my partition with GParted?

Tags: lubuntu, gparted, unallocated, crunchbang

Here is the situation with two pics in live usb. I have lubuntu and bunsenlab in the two ext. bunsen runned in live to extend partitions

[image: begin]

[image: end]

Error details

GParted Details

```
GParted 0.19.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
Libparted 3.2
```

Move `/dev/sda5` to the right and shrink it from 247.02 GiB to 149.37 GiB ( ERROR )

calibrate `/dev/sda5` ( SUCCESS )

```
path: /dev/sda5
start: 98723840
end: 616763391
size: 518039552 (247.02 GiB)
```

Check file system on `/dev/sda5` for errors and (if possible) fix them ( ERROR )

```
e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sda5
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/sda5 has unsupported feature(s): metadata_csum
e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!
```

Move `/dev/sda8` to the right and shrink it from 4.67 GiB to 4.39 GiB

Grow `/dev/sda7` from 23.28 GiB to 121.22 GiB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, right after the ERROR line it says

```
/dev/sda5 has unsupported feature(s): metadata_csum
e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!
```

So there's your problem.

It looks like you're running a debian live iso? I can't tell but it looks like their version (from stable or old-stable or even older) of e2fsck just doesn't support your partition.

You can check the version of e2fsck by running `e2fsck -V` or check with a package manager like Synaptic, and possibly upgrade it there.

Or you can download a newer live ISO.